# Connect to SQL server with custom port while executing installer

Tags: mysql, installshield, basic-msi

I have InstallShield 2013 basic MSI project. During installer execution I need to connect to MySQL Server which is running on 3310 port. Default port is 3306 and installation runs successfully, but when I try to connect to server with different port - installer cannot connect to MySQL server.

I tried to set custom port like described [here](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?149337-SQL-install-to-custom-port-number)

```
ServerName,3310
```

But it didn't work for me. I also tried to connect by IP of server and port delimited with ":" but it also had no effect.

When I try to connect to server by typing `hostname` I get this error: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname'"

When I try to connect to MySQL server by typing `hostname,port` I get the following error: "Unknown MySQL server host 'hostname,port'"

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or what I need to do to connect to MySQL server with custom port?

Comment: It is the MySQL server

Comment: -1 So, please edit your question removing all references to SQL Server. I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I have already edited my question.